# How to enable the UDP and TCP in Azure

Tags: android, azure, wowza

I am are working on streaming from android using "wowza" and We have installed  Wowza on Virtual Machine in Azure VM.

For "Wowza" streaming  we needs to enable PORT-RANGE from 6970 to 9999.

Please suggest how can I enable all endpoints range 6970 to 9999?

We have tried on amazon server it working fine by enabling unbound and inbound in server setting.

Answer (score 0):

How you do this will depend on if you created the Virtual Machine under the Azure Service Management tooling (also known as classic in the portal) or using Azure Resource Management (also known as ARM). When you are in the portal.azure.com preview portal it can tell you which you've got the VM deployed to as it will either be under the "virtual machines (classic)" or just "virtual machines".

I'm not sure what you are doing will work with the Service Management (classic) machines. You can [create endpoint mappings](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-set-up-endpoints/), but it doesn't support creation of ranges. You could create the manually one by one, or using PowerShell, but there is also a limit to the number of endpoints (currently 150 I think) that can be created due to the classic machines being hosted in the Cloud Services container.

For the Azure Resource Manager machines (ARM) you have to [set up the Network Security Group](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-nsg/). You can use the portal, an ARM deployment or even PowerShell to do this.